# Why PHPmailer is not sending attachment?

Tags: php, phpmailer

If I use the following code directly to a file e.g. test.php page then it sends the email with the attachment.

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from address';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = '<h1>hello message</h1>';
$email->AddAddress( 'to@gmail.com' );
$file_to_attach =  $path = '/home/xxxx/public_html/pdf/'.'1254.pdf';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , '1254.pdf' );
return $email->Send();
```

But If I send the email with attachment with the above same code **using a method of a class** then it's not sending the attachment (message body is sending).

**Mail class:**

```
public static function sendMail ($to, $subject, $message, $from, $fromName, $attachment, $attachmentName) {

    $email            = new PHPMailer();

    $email->isHTML(true);
    $email->From      = $from;
    $email->FromName  = $fromName;
    $email->Subject   = $subject;
    $email->Body      = $message;
    $email->AddAddress($to);    
    $file_to_attach   = $attachment;
    $email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , $attachmentName ); 

    return $email->Send();

}
```

**Sending Email:**

```
$path           = '/home/xxx/public_html/pdf/'.$confirm_id.'.pdf';
$pathFileName   = $confirm_id.'.pdf';

$message = "Hello $name";    

$confirmMail = Mail::sendMail($email, "xxxx pdf confirmation", $message, "xxxx@xxxx.org", "xxxx.org", $path, $pathFileName );

if(!$confirmMail) {
    echo 'Confirmation mail is not sent';
}
```

Can you tell me where I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: **Debug it** [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) the values, and check the file exists [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I sent this`$path` and '$pathFileName' value to the email message body and its value is correct.

Comment: Sending strings wont tell you if the file exists or is readable...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone let me check it.

Comment: Maybe it run into it in PHPMailer class so it don't send attach file
 if (!@is_file($path)) {
                throw new Exception($this->lang('file_access') . $path, self::STOP_CONTINUE);
            }

Comment: Also check `$email->SMTPDebug = 3` output.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks a lot for finding the error. I was sending the attachment before it actually saves to the directory. Like :)